# Javascript: createElement() para crear elementos anidados?

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

se me solicita crear un nuevo elemento con DOM mediante Javascript dentro de un `<ul></ul>` pero dentro de este `<li>` en el HTML entregado tienen el siguiente formato. `<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat</li>`.

Lo que estoy haciendo es un TodoList,  he podido crear el nuevo elemento `<li>` pero no se como agregar que este dentro de una etiqueta `<span>` a la vez y que tenga el icono a su lado.

Mi codigo HTML (Viene dado, se me solicita no modicarlo):

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 class="todo-header">To do List</h1>
        <input id="addToDo" type="text" placeholder="Add to do here" />
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Y el codigo Javascript que he creado es el siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("addToDo").addEventListener("keyup", function todoList() {
    var item = document.getElementById("addToDo").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.appendChild(text);

    if (event.keyCode === 13) { //keycode de tecla enter
        document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(newItem);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("addToDo").addEventListener("keyup", function todoList() {
    var item = document.getElementById("addToDo").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var itag = document.createElement("i");
    itag.className = "fa fa-trash";
    span.appendChild(itag);
    newItem.appendChild(span);
    newItem.appendChild(text);
    
    if (event.keyCode === 13) { //keycode de tecla enter
        document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(newItem);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1 class="todo-header">To do List</h1>
        <input id="addToDo" type="text" placeholder="Add to do here" />
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat
            </li>
            
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Nada mas te faltaba crear el `span`, el `i` para agregar clases puedes hacer uso de `Element.className`